# Invalid type for substring function

Tags: sql-server

I have a message error

> Invalid int argument data type for substring function argument 1.

I don't understand why!

```
UPDATE DBO.NUMBER
SET NUMBER = 22675442455
WHERE SUBSTRING(ID,1,2) NOT IN ('67','68')
```

Comment: What's the data type of `ID`?

Comment: data type of id is a INT

Comment: That's your problem; `SUBSTRING` expects a string as first argument

Comment: Why not just `WHERE NOT (ID >= 67000000000 AND ID < 69000000000)`

Comment: I *suppose* they want to omit rows where `ID` has the value 67, 68, 670, 671, 672...689, 6700, 6701, ...6899... Too, @Charlieface .

Comment: @Larnu Then it probably shouldn't be an `int` in the first place....

Comment: @Charlieface bc I want to except some Number and the way I do it is cleaner

Comment: Doesn't look very clean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUBSTRING` required first argument as `STRING`, so simply convert it to `VARCHAR`.

```
UPDATE DBO.NUMBER
SET NUMBER = 22675442455
WHERE SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),ID)),1,2) NOT IN ('67','68')
```